# mv: Cannot stat - No such file or directory

Tags: bash, file-rename, mv, nosuchfileexception

I have piped the output of ls command into a file. [The contents](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/5yWQ62xqmojPw9NVkItr/) are like so:

```
[Chihiro]_Grisaia_no_Kajitsu_-_01_[1920x816_Blu-ray_FLAC][D2B961D6].mkv
[Chihiro]_Grisaia_no_Kajitsu_-_02_[1920x816_Blu-ray_FLAC][38F88A81].mkv
[Chihiro]_Grisaia_no_Kajitsu_-_03_[1920x816_Blu-ray_FLAC][410F74F7].mkv
```

My attempt to rename these episodes according to episode number is as follows:

```
cat grisaia | while read line; 
   #get the episode number
   do EP=$(echo $line | egrep -o  "_([0-9]{2})_" | cut -d "_" -f2)
   if [[ $EP ]]
      #escape special characters
      then line=$(echo $line | sed 's/\[/\\[/g' | sed 's/\]/\\]/g')
      mv "$line" "Grisaia_no_Kajitsu_${EP}.mkv"
   fi
done
```

The mv commands exit with code 1 with the following error:

> mv: cannot stat
>   '\[Chihiro\]_Grisaia_no_Kajitsu_-*01*\[1920x816_Blu-ray_FLAC\]\[D2B961D6\].mkv':
>   No such file or directory

What I really don't get is that if I copy the file that could not be stat and attempt to stat the file, it works. I can even take the exact same string that is output and execute the mv command individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you surround your variable (`$line`) with double quotes (`"`) you don't need to escape those special characters. So you have two options there:

1. Remove the following assignation completely:

   ```
   then # line=$(echo $line | sed 's/\[/\\[/g' | sed 's/\]/\\]/g')`
   ```

   or
2. Remove the double quotes in the following line:

   ```
   mv $line "Grisaia_no_Kajitsu_${EP}.mkv"
   ```

---

### Further considerations

1. Parsing the output of `ls` is never a good idea. Think about filenames with spaces. See [this document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more information.
2. The `cat` here is unnecessary:

   ```
   cat grisaia | while read line; 
       ...
   done
   ```

   Use this instead to avoid an unnecessary pipe:

   ```
   while read line; 
       ...
   done < grisaia
   ```

---

### Why is good to avoid pipes in some scenarios? (answering comment)

Pipes create subshells (which are expensive), and you can also make some mistakes as the following:

```
last=""

cat grisaia | while read line; do
    last=$line
done

echo $last # surprise!! it outputs an empty string
```

The reason is that `$last` inside the loop belongs to another subshell.

Now, see the same approach wothout pipes:

```
while read line; do
    last=$line
done < grisaia

echo $last # it works as expected and prints the last line
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there really any significant difference between cat and < functionally? It seems like just a preference

Comment: I added more information to the answer regarding pipes.

Comment: That pretty much covers it.

Comment: Very high quality answer. Thank you